# SQL query for selecting count from grouped columns of latest records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table on SQL:

```
record_type | user | date
type_1      | user1| 2018-09-27T09:13:15.946545
type_2      | user1| 2018-09-27T09:13:30.052329
type_1      | user1| 2018-09-27T09:11:18.724686
type_2      | user1| 2018-09-27T08:11:18.724686
type_1      | user2| 2018-09-25T09:13:15.946545
type_2      | user2| 2018-09-25T09:13:30.052329
type_1      | user2| 2018-09-25T09:11:18.724686
type_2      | user2| 2018-09-25T08:11:18.724686
```

I need to count how many users for a `record_type` have data older than X days. 
Expected result for record older than a day is:

```
record_type | count
type_1      | 2 
type_2      | 2
```

This is my query:

```
select record_type, count(*) 
from (select record_type, user, max(date) as MaxDate
      from table
      group by record_type, user 
      having to_timestamp(max(date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.M') < NOW() - interval '15' day  
      order by MaxDate desc
) as test
group by record_type;
```

This works, but I wonder if there's a better way?

Comment: Please take a look at our [SQL tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/sql/info) information.  We require context, the schema and output of `explain select`. You got a good start, but it's not complete yet. Please take a good look at the link provided and improve the quality of your question.